# Button to hide element in expandablelistview child

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview, visibility

I have 2 `buttons` in my `expandablelistiview` child, first button `View.VISIBLE`, and another one `View.GONE`. I tried to make the first button change the second button visibility become visible, but it's not working.

My **getchildview** method:

```
@Override
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView,
    ViewGroup parent) {

    final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }

    buttonOff = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_off);

    buttonOff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            buttonOff.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            buttonTest.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });

    buttonTest = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_test);
    buttonTest.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    buttonTest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            buttonTest.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            buttonOff.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });

    TextView listChildText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item);

    listChildText.setText(childText);

    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not working because you are not maintaining the state of the buttons. Initialize button state for all of your rows. Then every time your getView() method is called, first check the state and depending on that you can set which button to make visible. When a button is clicked you need to update the status of that row. Below code can guide you in that direction:

```
@Override
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView,
                         ViewGroup parent) {

    final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    // get visibility status of the first button
    final boolean buttonOffVisible = getFirstButtonVisibility(groupPosition, childPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }

    buttonOff = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_off);

    buttonOff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // set the state of the first button
            setFirstButtonVisibility(groupPosition, childPosition, false); // false denoting as GONE

            buttonOff.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            buttonTest.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });

    buttonTest = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_test);
    // buttonTest.setVisibility(View.GONE);    <-- remove this line

    buttonTest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // set the state of the first button
            setFirstButtonVisibility(groupPosition, childPosition, true); // true denoting as VISIBLE

            buttonTest.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            buttonOff.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });

    // depending upon the visibility status of first button, make one of the two visible
    if(buttonOffVisible) {
        buttonOff.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        buttonTest.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    else {
        buttonOff.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        buttonTest.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    TextView listChildText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item);

    listChildText.setText(childText);

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as a newbie, what is getFirstButtonVisibility() ?

Comment: getFirstButtonVisibility() and setFirstButtonVisibility() are methods that you need to implement. First create a class level variable, say hashmap, which would map your row to the button state. Then get and set values through the methods or access the hashmap directly. Try to implement yourself, it will help you learn